# angular router param match regex

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would like to start all of my url's with a language which match an array of strings or a Regex

`const languages = ['nl', 'en', 'de', 'fr']` or `const languageRegex = /(nl|en|de|fr)/g`

my routeConfig is as follows

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'en/configuration',
    },
    {
        children: [
            { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'configuration' },
            {
                loadChildren:
                    '../modules/booking-flow/configuration.module#ConfigurationModule',
                path: RouteHelper.paths.configuration,
            },
            {
                loadChildren:
                    '../modules/booking-flow/personal-info.module#PersonalInfoModule',
                path: RouteHelper.paths.personalInfo,
            },
            {
                loadChildren:
                    '../modules/booking-flow/summary.module#SummaryModule',
                path: RouteHelper.paths.summary,
            },
            {
                loadChildren:
                    '../modules/booking-flow/payment-method.module#PaymentMethodModule',
                path: RouteHelper.paths.paymentMethod,
            },
            {
                loadChildren:
                    '../modules/booking-flow/confirmation.module#ConfirmationModule',
                path: RouteHelper.paths.confirmation,
            },
            {
                component: ErrorPageComponent,
                path: RouteHelper.paths.errorNotFound,
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: RouteHelper.paths.errorNotFound,
            },
        ],
        component: null,
        path: ':language',
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    },
];
```

It is a pity this doesn't work, it's a pretty readable config in my opinion:

`path: ':language(/nl|en|de|fr/g)',`

I would like to get the following pattern.

- `/` redirects to `/en/configuration` works
- `/nl` redirects to `/nl/configuration` works
- `/es` redirects to `404` doesn't work
- `/es/configuration` redirects to `404` doesn't work
- `/en/invalid` redirects to `/en/404` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as i see, you won't achieve that with just router configuration, it doesn't have such capabilities. Instead you can use **RouteGuard** to check whether `language` parameter is in `['nl', 'en', 'de', 'fr']`, and if it doesn't you can just return an **UrlTree** (in case of angular 7.1+) of **not found page** or redirect user **manually** with **router** (angular <= 7.1).

### The guard can look like this:

```
const allowedLanguages = ['nl', 'en', 'de', 'fr'];

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LanguageGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.next.params.pipe(
        map(params => {
            return params && allowedLanguages.includes(params.language)
               ? true
               : this.router.parseUrl(RouteHelper.paths.errorNotFound)
        })
    );
  }
}
```

Afterwards you just need to apply this guard to your parent route. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, got it working now. I was too focussed on the router param, forgot all about guards.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad that it helped

Answer (score 0):

I think there are better ways to solve your problem; if indeed your problem is related to supporting different languages in your application.

[ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) is a supported, well known/documented library that allows you to internationalise your application, without much hassle.

The library allows you to provide the languages that your application supports, where you'll supply JSON files containing the correct language translations you require, per language you support.

They'll look like this:

```
{
    "title": "My title"
}
```

The library provides pipes, directives, which can be used in HTML like this:

```
<span translate>title</span>

<span> {{ 'title' | translate }}</span>
```

Both would render `My Title` - within a span element.

The library allows you to do much more, such as parameter interpolation - where you can pass dynamic values to your translations. It also provides services for you to make translations within your code.

Comment: Already using ngx-translate, but with pre-render i want to create static files (URLs) of each language version to speed up performance. Just need to resolve the JSON for the translation when compiling now :)